# CSS-only solution for overflow/scroll indicators

Tags: css

I've got some scroll indicator done with CSS only. This works pretty much everywhere and is great. The only problem is that, if the box doesn't overflow (first box), then the content of the box is not aligned to the left. Any ideas how to do this? Also: Feel free to use this code :)

```css
html {
  background: #FFF;
}

.scrollbox ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
      -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
          flex: 1 0 auto;
  margin-left: -4rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.scrollbox {
  outline: 1px dotted black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
      -ms-flex-pack: start;
          justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
          flex-wrap: nowrap;
  word-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: #FFF no-repeat;
  background-image:
    -webkit-radial-gradient(0 50%, farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 50%, farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image:
    -o-radial-gradient(0 50%, farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    -o-radial-gradient(100% 50%, farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 0 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 100% 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
  background-size: 1rem 100%;
}

.scrollbox::before,
.scrollbox::after {
  content: '';
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    width: 2rem;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
        -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
            flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.scrollbox::before {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top, right top,from(#FFF),color-stop(50%, #FFF),to(rgba(255,255,255,0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#FFF,#FFF 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left,#FFF,#FFF 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0));
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#FFF,#FFF 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0));
}

.scrollbox::after {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top, right top,from(rgba(255,255,255,0)),color-stop(50%, #FFF),to(#FFF));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(255,255,255,0),#FFF 50%,#FFF);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(255,255,255,0),#FFF 50%,#FFF);
  background: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,255,255,0),#FFF 50%,#FFF);
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollbox">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="scrollbox">
  <ul>
    <li>Ah! Scroll right!</li>
    <li>2 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>3 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>4 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>5 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>6 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>7 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>8 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>9 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>1 Lorem Ipsum0</li>
    <li>1 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>2 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>3 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>4 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>5 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>6 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>7 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>8 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>9 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>1 Lorem Ipsum0</li>
    <li>1 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>2 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>3 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>4 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>5 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>6 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>7 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>8 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>The end!</li>
    <li>No shadow there.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

- change `width: 2rem;` to `min-width: 2rem;`
- add `max-width: 2rem;` on `.scrollbox::before`

I have only looked at it on Chrome (macOS and Andriod).

```css
html {
  background: #FFF;
}

.scrollbox ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
      -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
          flex: 1 0 auto;
  margin-left: -4rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.scrollbox {
  outline: 1px dotted black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
      -ms-flex-pack: start;
          justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
          flex-wrap: nowrap;
  word-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: #FFF no-repeat;
  background-image:
    -webkit-radial-gradient(0 50%, farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 50%, farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image:
    -o-radial-gradient(0 50%, farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    -o-radial-gradient(100% 50%, farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 0 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 100% 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
  background-size: 1rem 100%;
}

.scrollbox::before,
.scrollbox::after {
  content: '';
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    min-width: 2rem;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
        -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
            flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.scrollbox::before {
  max-width: 2rem;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top, right top,from(#FFF),color-stop(50%, #FFF),to(rgba(255,255,255,0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#FFF,#FFF 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left,#FFF,#FFF 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0));
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#FFF,#FFF 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0));
}

.scrollbox::after {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top, right top,from(rgba(255,255,255,0)),color-stop(50%, #FFF),to(#FFF));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(255,255,255,0),#FFF 50%,#FFF);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(255,255,255,0),#FFF 50%,#FFF);
  background: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,255,255,0),#FFF 50%,#FFF);
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollbox">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="scrollbox">
  <ul>
    <li>Ah! Scroll right!</li>
    <li>2 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>3 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>4 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>5 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>6 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>7 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>8 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>9 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>1 Lorem Ipsum0</li>
    <li>1 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>2 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>3 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>4 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>5 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>6 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>7 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>8 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>9 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>1 Lorem Ipsum0</li>
    <li>1 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>2 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>3 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>4 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>5 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>6 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>7 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>8 Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>The end!</li>
    <li>No shadow there.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `padding-left: 0` in your `.scrollbox ul` - it has padding by default

Comment: This makes it better, but doesn't fix the problem!