# Adding horizontal scrolling shadows effect

Tags: css, mobile, bootstrap-4

I want to add an inset shadow to indicate that there is more content to scroll. The best way I can explain it is with a drawing:

[image]

I'm using Bootstrap as a framework and this is exactly what I'm working on:

Below is the code:

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45105611/923560

Answer (score 12):

You can do Horizontal scrolling shadows effect with following background css.

```
.table-responsive{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, white), linear-gradient(to right, white, white), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 20, .50), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 20, .50), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  /* Shadows */
  /* Shadow covers */
  background-position: left center, right center, left center, right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: 20px 100%, 20px 100%, 10px 100%, 10px 100%;
  background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3oxq1ju6/1/

Comment: HDP, thanks for your response. But what I really want is something dynamic, that adds and removes the shadow depending on which side the overflow is in.

Comment: have you checked demo? it is working dynamic as you want.

Comment: I was using Chrome and it doesn't work on it. But now I used Safari and Firefox and it worked perfectly on them. Thanks! Is there a way to make it work on Chrome as well?

Comment: I have check latest Chrome version and, it is working in Chrome. Please try to check in latest version of Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: @HDP It doesn't work well on Chrome on a Mac laptop with the latest version of Chrome. It works when I use an external display monitor but with the built in laptop display it doesn't work...

Comment: Just wanted to add to this that if you plan on using the same color for your gradients as your background color it will not work. It makes sense since it is a background image, which goes behind your child elements.

Comment: Please give credit to where you copied this, assuming that's the case...(i.e. http://lea.verou.me/2012/04/background-attachment-local/)

Comment: This solution does not work in situations where the nested  `<tr>` elements have a background, e.g .`tr {background: red;}`. It doesn't work because the scrolling shadow effect is attached behind rows, with the row's background color covering it. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: This works well on current versions of Chrome, Safari and Firefox. It doesn't show the shadow until you scroll on Edge, however.

Comment: won't work if you want a transparent background